# rick & morty api problem with request on character with an id

Tags: javascript, redux-saga

I would like to make a request about the api rick and morty. To get the details of a character, you have to specify an id as a parameter:**"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/id"**

I use redux-saga to fetch my request, but the request fails with a message: 
   **" Hey! that parameter is not allowed, try with a number instead;)"**

I tried the request with the id received in my component and the request is effective. I think it comes either from my action or my saga.......

here is my action :

```
export const getCharactersDetails = () => {
  return { type: GET_CHARACTER_DETAILS }
}
```

here is my saga :

```
const getLatestDetails = (id) => 
fetch('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/' + id);


export function* fetchCharacterDetails() {
 try {

let myCharacter;
const response = yield call(getLatestDetails);
const result = yield response.json();

if (result.error) {
  yield put({ type: DETAILS_REQUEST_FAILED, error: result.error });
} else {
  myCharacters = result.results
  yield put({ type: DETAILS_RECEIVED, character: myCharacter });
}

} catch (error) {
  yield put({ type: DETAILS_REQUEST_FAILED, error: error.message });
}

}

function* actionWatcher() {
 yield takeLatest(GET_CHARACTERS, fetchCharacters)
 yield takeLatest(GET_CHARACTER_DETAILS, fetchCharacterDetails)
}
```

and i call my action like that:

```
let CharacterId = this.props.navigation.state.params.id
this.props.dispatch(getCharactersDetails(CharacterId))
```

any idea what I'm not doing right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing any ID to your `getLatestDetails` function.

Add the ID to the action you are creating:

```
export const getCharactersDetails = id => {
  return { type: GET_CHARACTER_DETAILS, id }
}
```

…then add the ID from the action as parameter to your saga and pass it as second argument to your `call` effect:

```
export function* fetchCharacterDetails({ id }) {
  try {
    let myCharacter;
      const response = yield call(getLatestDetails, id);
      const result = response.json();

      if (result.error) {
        yield put({ type: DETAILS_REQUEST_FAILED, error: result.error });
      } else {
        myCharacters = result.results
        yield put({ type: DETAILS_RECEIVED, character: myCharacter });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      yield put({ type: DETAILS_REQUEST_FAILED, error: error.message });
    }
}
```

Additional explanation:

- The saga gets the action as argument; we are using destructuring here to get just the ID (note the curly braces)
- `call` accepts the function to be called as first parameter, followed by additional arguments passed to the function, this is how `getLatestDetails` gets the ID
- I removed `yield` before `response.json()`, this is just a plain old synchronous operation

Comment: Great, thanks. 
and I can't pass this id into my:  
 yield takeLatest(GET_CHARACTER_DETAILS, fetchCharacterDetails)  ?  

because now the request passes but characters are undefined:                          {type: "DETAILS_RECEIVED", characters: undefined, @@redsaga/SAGA_ACTION: true}

Comment: `takeLatest` will pass the incoming action to the argument list of the saga. So that part is correct now. I think the problem is you're passing in `character`, but your `DETAILS_RECEIVED` action expects `characters` (plural)

Comment: Also, there is no need to put a `yield` before `response.json()`, this is just a plain old synchronous operation